# "accepted to [conference name]" vs. "accepted at [conference name]"

Tags: prepositions

Should one say

> This paper was accepted **to** ACL.

or

> This paper was accepted **at** ACL.

? (ACL is the name of an academic conference)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! I believe these are both wrong!

"Accepted to" is simply incorrect. That's not proper English.

If the paper is accepted *at* ACL, then ACL is an event (like a party), and the paper is accepted at that time and place. Like saying: there is a New Year party *at* my house.  That means: you visited the conference, and they only accepted your paper, after you got there.  I am pretty sure that's not what you want to say.

I think you want to say that the paper was accepted *for* ACL, meaning that ACL will happen later, but they want your paper to be there, at that later time.

(PROTIP: Tell us what you actually want to say, next time.)

Comment: Got it, thanks! "I think you want to say that the paper was accepted for ACL, meaning that ACL will happen later, but they want your paper to be there, at that later time." Correct

Answer (score 0):

Accepted by is the most appropriate in the context you have provided.

Comment: Why the downvote?